# Powershell script that outputs integer

Tags: powershell, integer, return-value

Colleagues, hello everyone!
I have a powershell script that returns type DataRow from MSSQL. How do I get an integer out of it?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific what output exactly you mean?

Comment: `$SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()`? Would be much easier.

Comment: Please provide an example of the ps1 you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be way easier:

```
$sqlCmd = $Connection.CreateCommand()
$sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM [Queues].[dbo].[database] WHERE [Date] > (DATEADD(minute, -5, GETUTCDATE()))"
$sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Comment: @Guardian You have fallen in the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). The _real_ question is "how do I get an integer value from SQL query into Zabbix?"

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry. I added .GetType () to the output, that's why Zabbix was cursing.
The error is now gone, thanks!